# Update nested child elements with jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-mongodb

I have a document with child elements of items like so

```
"bar" : "d bar",
"items" : [ 
        {       
            "message" : "one",
            "display" : "true",
            "type" : "text"     
        } 
        {       
            "message" : "one2",
            "display" : "true",
            "type" : "text2"     
        }
        {       
            "message" : "one2",
            "display" : "false",
            "type" : "text3"     
        }
]
```

I want to update the fields that are 'one2' in the array to 'one22'. I'm writing this command, but it only updates the first value.

```
Bars::where('bar', 'd bar')
    ->where('items.message', 'one2')
    ->update(['items.$.message' => 'one22']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but maybe the answer will help others.

If you change your query just a little it should work:

```
Bars::where('bar', 'd bar')
    ->where('items.message', 'one2')
    ->update(['items.$[].message' => 'one22']);
```

From MongoDB Docs:

> - **$**
>   Acts as a placeholder to update the first element that matches the query condition.
> - **$[]**
>   Acts as a placeholder to update all elements in an array for the documents that match the query condition.

Comment: This is not working in laravel. are you sure?

Comment: @AmitShah My comment is a year old but worked at the time with jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. Which part is not working anymore? The 'where' queries are working but the 'update' query isn't? 
Is it not updating at all or just the first match?

Comment: the notation of `items.$[].message` not working in `update()` function. i tried.

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure for the multidimensional array as above, but if this can be done on single dimension array as below then should work for 2nd level too.*

My workaround solution for Laravel.MongoDB:

```php
$user = Player::firstOrCreate(['email' => strtolower($email)]);
$user->items = array_merge( (array) $user->items ?? [], ['key'=>'val']);
```

This will create `items` attribute if not exists or append in existing.